# Pass data between UITabBarController views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I have searched for an entire day for a simple example on this and haven't found it yet. I am working on an app and I want to make an API call on the initial load and populate some variables that will be accessible in any of the tab views.

Example: I want to make a single API call to get my data which will include data relating to alerts for the alerts tab. I want to use this data on the initial load to update the "Alerts" tab badge. However, I want to also use that information on the alerts page once the person goes to that tab without having to make another API call to get the same information again.

I have read a ton of explanations that do not fit my requirements, so I am looking for a good example to help me out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use your `UITabBarViewController`'s `viewControllers` property to access the array of view controllers in your tab bar controller. Typecast them according to your architecture of tab bar controller.
Then get a pointer to any of view controller using that array.

For example, say your tab bar controller has 5 tabs, each tab having a `UINavigationController` which has particular `UIViewController` as root view controllers. Say you want to set badge value of 3rd tab to your web response array count. You can do that as

```
[[[self.tabviewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2] 
        setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[myArray count]];
```

You can also get to particular view controller's property by typecasting the view controllers. For example

```
MyViewController *myVc = (MyViewController*) [[(UINavigationController*)[[self.tabviewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
[myVc setPropertyName:propertyValue];
```

Comment: This method allows me to update the badge correctly, but in the view for that controller, I also want to have access to the NSArray that I used in the initial controller. I basically want to make a single API call on the first controller I load, and have all the other controllers access that data when they are loaded.

Comment: @Donovan If any of your view controller in the tab bar controller wants to access that array, make a property of `NSArray` and when you are done with processing your API response, assign your response array to the view controller's property array.

Answer (score 2):

I had this question typed up since yesterday and made sure to search before posting. There was no question similar that I found that had the answer, and it may be very straight forward or maybe this is not the way to do it but here is how I solved this issue: using [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the code example on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089462/1084306)

Answer (score 1):

Put all of those variables in a single class and access a shared instance of it whenever you want.
Add

```
+ (YourClass *)sharedObject
{
    static YourClass *sharedClassObject = nil;
    if (sharedClassObject == nil) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            sharedClassObject = [[YourClass alloc] init];
            //Initialise it here if necessary
        });
    }

    return sharedClassObject;
}
```

To access the shared instance, simply use `[YourClass sharedObject]`.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? Your answer is not very useful without it.

Comment: This is what I ended up using. I have 2 tabs: ViewController and TableViewController. I have a model that I init within my ViewController and I need to use a array from the view and pass to my TableViewController

Answer (score 1):

Put the data in your app delegate object. You can access it from anywhere in your app by `(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`, or you can give each of your view controllers an explicit link to it.

NSUserDefaults isn't really meant for sharing data globally in your app, although it would get the job done. It also has the benefit that the information sticks around if your app can't connect to the server next time. Is that a good thing or a bad thing?

Comment: I tried this and was able to successfully set the data of an "AppDelegate" variable I created. The problem with this method was when I tried to access that data in another controller, I was unable to. Always returned null.

Comment: Also in my case, it would be good to have the data stick around in the app, in case the next time they load, they do not have an internet connection. This way I should not need to write any other data to the device, if this built in functionality can handle it and cache it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSNotificationCenter to post the notification that new data arrived and your new data as an object.

Each of the viewControllers that need that object should just subscribe to that notification and just consume the new data.