# How get data from View to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, getter

I have a `UITabBarController`, which has `3 UIViewControllers`. Each controller has a few `UITextFields`. In `UItabBarController` is  a button "save". Please, how can I get data from `UITextFields` in `UIViewControllores`? I need the data from all `UITextFields` and from all `UIViewControllers` in `UITabBarController` (in IBAction of save button). How can I do it? Thanks.

Here is picture of my TabBarController on Storyboard.

[image]

The first ViewController has a class StudentVC. The class has one text field. In **StudentVC.m** is this code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CoreDataHelper.h"

@interface StudentVC :  UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectID *selectedStudentID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *studentNameTextField;

@end
```

The studentNameTextField is connected with field in Storyboard. Then I have a class for TabBar the class name is StudentTBC. In file **StudentTBC.m** I have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (debug == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];

    StudentVC *studentVC = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    studentVC.studentNameTextField.text = @"asad";
}
```

So, when I go on TabBar I will see in studentNameTextField the text "asad", but the field is clear... So I added also in IBAction:save this code:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    if (debug == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }

    StudentVC *studentVC = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *string = studentVC.studentNameTextField.text;
    NSLog(@"string:%@", string);
```

But when I insert the field and press "ulozit" (its save in czech), I get a "string: null" instead of a "string: textWhichIWriteToField". I tried indexes 0,1,2 but nothing works. :/

**Edited 3.4 15:20**

I did a move of my application. In first part is my storyboard - UITabBarController and 3UIViewControllers. I deleted a Navagition Controllers. In second part I do again a Outlets. Third part is code of save function (the code could be write a content of textfield) and code of ViewDidLoad of TabBarController (code could be set a  string of textfield). The last part is run application (the result is in console - null string and clear textfield).
I also tried print this:

```
NSInteger countOfViews = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers count];
NSLog(@"count:%ld", (long)countOfViews);
```

It has to be three? or? Because my result was 0.. Why? :/

My movie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6p__e48lLI&feature=youtu.be

**EDITED 2.4 20:58 -------------------**

Hello. I tried all options but nothing worked.. So I did a new SIMPLE application, where is only one UITabBarController with two UIViewControllers and one UITableViewController (because of navigation bar). Please download the project and try it yourself. Only run, then click on button "TabBar" and you are on the UITabBarController. When you press a Save button, it should display a count of UIViewsControllers and the value of textfields. Could you please try and tell me what's wrong? Thank you. Here is the project:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4jlzadr2us00ad/TBC.zip

Comment: You will have to use segues. 
Check this out, it should help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997037/pass-data-between-uitabbarcontroller-views

Comment: While the answer you linked to is correct, your description isn't. This has absolutely nothing to do with segues.

Comment: You didn't mention about Navigaiton Controller between TabBar and ViewController. All you need to modify code a bit (look at my modified answer)

Comment: Damit..It's necessary use a Navigation controllers? I don't know. I'm beginner and saw it in a tutorial.

Comment: Please check update of my question. I deleted navigation controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access to one of text field you can use code below:

```
- (IBAction)save {
    YourUIViewController *vc = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexOfController];
    NSString *str = vc.yourTextField.text;
}
```

EDIT. You have me how your controllers are connected and now i realized you got `UINavigaitonController` after `UIViewController`. Modified code should look like:

```
- (IBAction)save {
    NSArray *navConArr = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexOfController];
    for(UINavigationController *nc in nacConArr) {
        UIViewController *vc = [nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"And your text is = %@", vc.studentNameTextField.text);
    }
}
```

**Updated**

I solved the problem finally... The right code for TabBarController

```
- (IBAction)save {
    YourUIViewController *vc = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexOfController];
    NSString *str = vc.yourTextField.text;
}
```

Comment: How can I get a viewController index please? When I have 3 UIViews, they have a indexes: 0,1,2 or not? Because I tried this indexes and the NSString is still null :/.

Comment: Property viewControllers is an array. You wrote your tabBarController contains 3 UIViewControllers (not UIView!) so using index 0, 1 and 2 you should access to one of them.

Comment: Yop I have UIViewControllers not UIView. Sorry for bad expression.

Comment: Anyway your question is not clear for me. Please add more code in your question please.

Comment: I tried it also with navigation controllers and your code and the NSArray navConrArr is null.

Comment: My code didn't work because IBAction is in UITabBarViewController NOT in UIViewController. Good luck!

Comment: Saved me a hell lot of time :) Thanks a bunch (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Please check **outlets** for **UITextFields**,

Also check output for

*NSLog(@"StudentVC textField -- %@",studentVC.studentNameTextField);* in save()

if it is also null, then there is definitely problem with your outlets.