# View based delegation in storyboards and UITabbarController

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I know this has been asked, but I can't figure out how to make this work with my app -- I'm sure I'm doing it wrong.

I have two view controllers embedded inside a `UITabBarViewContoller`, `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. `SecondViewController` is nothing more then a few `UITextFields` for managing a hostname and port that the app connects to.

FirstViewController contains most of the code (which I know isn't very MVC oriented). I'm trying to implement Delegation from `SecondViewController` back to `FirstViewController` ([Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)) but it seems like my delegate methods aren't being called. Since this is based on storyboards, I'm not creating the instance of `SecondViewController` and I'm not sure how to set the Delegate. Is there a way to access the instance of `SecondViewController` so I can set the Delegate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997037/pass-data-between-uitabbarcontroller-views

Answer (score 0):

milesper thank you!

My solution (in swift)

```
    let secondView = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as SecondViewController
    secondView.delegate = self
```